# Getting 404 not found error with Sitecore.HabitatHome.Omni on http://habitatfitness.dev.local/sitecore/api/habitatfitness/sports/facet?sc_apikey={key}

Tags: jss, personalization, layout-service

I was doing some research on Sitecore.HabitatHome.Omni. It is working fine at my local instance but getting an error while setting up personalization. I got a 404 status code while submitting the form in a personalization wizard.

The request was failing with (`/demographics/facet`) and (`/demographics/profile`). This is also happening with (`/sports/facet`) and (`/sports/profile`).

I need your help to understand the purpose of this call, where can I find it at server side and how can I configure or customize it.
Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you deployed the server part of the demo? https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Omni/blob/master/docs/configuration/installation.md#server